# Print taxonomy term name in node.tpl.php

Tags: 6, theming

How can I print the taxonomy term name in node.tpl.php?

The following prints the name as a link, but I just want to print the name as text so I can make it a `<div>` class.

```
<?php print $terms ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$term = current($node->taxonomy);
echo '<div class="some-class">' . $term->name . '</div>';
```